# cakePHP - Call to a member function findById() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakePHP, please advice.

The database name is admin_accounts. Here is data.
[image]
 
The class file

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class AdminAccount extends AppModel {

}
?>
```

The controller file

```
<?php
    class AdminAccountsController extends AppController{

    public function profile($id = null){
        if(!$id){ throw new NotFoundException(__('No profile')); }

        $adminAccount = $ $this->AdminAccount->findById($id);
        if (!$adminAccount) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('No profile'));
        }
        $this->set('admin_account', $adminAccount);
    }

    }
?>
```

When I call the profile, it gave me this error

```
Warning (4096): Object of class AdminAccountsController could not be converted to string   [APP/Controller/AdminAccountsController.php, line 15]
Notice (8): Object of class AdminAccountsController to string conversion [APP/Controller/AdminAccountsController.php, line 15]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: Object [APP/Controller/AdminAccountsController.php, line 15]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/AdminAccountsController.php, line 15]
Fatal error: Call to a member function findById() on a non-object in /home/crayzest/public_html/cake/app/Controller/AdminAccountsController.php on line 15
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: this line: `$adminAccount = $ $this->AdminAccount->findById($id);` remove the extra `$`

Comment: OMG! I totally overlooked the $ Thank you so much!

Comment: In general it is wise to closely listen to the Warning/Error message.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove the extra `$` sign .

And , secondly load the Model before you use findById() function.

Write This before findbyId() statement

```
$this->loadModel('AdminAccount');
```